# How avoid scroll snap y direction during using x scroll snap direction?

Tags: html, css

My page is long in y direction. I set scroll snap point in x direction on wide div. When i use scroll snap point in x direction it also snap page in y direction. How i can exclude y direction or block somehow?

I try:

```
.slides {
       display: flex;
       overflow:-x: auto;
       scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
       scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

Edit: html:

```
          <div class="slider">
            <a href="#1">1</a>
            <a href="#2">2</a>
            <a href="#3">3</a>


            <div class="slides">
              <div id="1">
                <img src="{{ r.image_field.url }}">
              </div>
              <div id="2}">
                <img src="{{ r.image_field2.url }}">
              </div>
              <div id="3">
                <img src="{{ r.image_field3.url }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: could you edit attaching the HTML of your code?